# format ssn using regex

Tags: c#, asp.net, regex

Hi I need regex in c sharp to display SSN in the format of xxx-xx-6789. i.e 123456789 should be displayed as xxx-xx-6789 in a textfield. The code I am using write now is

```
string SSN = "123456789";
Regex ssnRegex = new Regex("(?:[0-9]{3})(?:[0-9]{2})(?:[0-9]{4})");
string formattedSSN = ssnRegex.Replace(SSN, "XXX-XX-${last}");
```

What is correct Reg Expression to mask ssn xxx-xx-6789 ?

Comment: string formattedSSN = "XXX-XX-" + SSN.Substring(SSN.Length - 4, 4);

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're using `last` as a named group in your replacement string without specifying it in your pattern.

Update your pattern as follows and your existing code should work:

```
(?:[0-9]{3})(?:[0-9]{2})(?<last>[0-9]{4})
```

Depending on your input you may want to restrict the pattern to match the entire input by using the `^` and `$` metacharacters to match the start and end of the string, respectively. By doing so the regex won't match an input with more than 9 consecutive numbers. This would look like:

```
^(?:[0-9]{3})(?:[0-9]{2})(?<last>[0-9]{4})$
```

Also, since all you care about is the last 4 digits, you might choose to match 5 numbers, followed by 4 numbers, instead of splitting it up into 3 groups:

```
^(?:[0-9]{5})(?<last>[0-9]{4})$
```

In addition, if your input is always 9 numbers and can be trusted, then regex is not needed. You could simply get the substring to extract the last 4 characters:

```
string SSN = "123456789";
string formattedSSN = "XXX-XX-" + SSN.Substring(SSN.Length - 4, 4);
```

Answer (score 1):

Generic code for SSN Masking.

```
    string originalSSN = Convert.ToString("123-456-789").PadLeft(9, '0');
        int maskDigit = 6;
        string maskSSN = originalSSN.Substring(originalSSN.Length - maskDigit, maskDigit);            
        if (Regex.IsMatch(maskSSN, "(—)|(–)|(-)"))
        {
            int i = maskDigit;
            while (Regex.Replace(maskSSN, "(—)|(–)|(-)", "").Length < maskDigit)
            {
                i++;
                maskSSN = originalSSN.Substring(originalSSN.Length - i, i);
            }

            string[] ssnArray = Regex.Split(maskSSN, "(—)|(–)|(-)", RegexOptions.ExplicitCapture);
            if (ssnArray.Length > 1)
            {
                maskSSN = originalSSN.Substring(originalSSN.Length - maskDigit - (ssnArray.Length - 1), maskDigit + (ssnArray.Length - 1));
            }

        }


        maskSSN = maskSSN.PadLeft(9, '#');
```

Answer (score 1):

How about this nice little function that will mask Tins as well as Ssns:

```
public static string MaskSSN(string originalSSN)
    {
        if (originalSSN.Length < 5) return originalSSN;
        var trailingNumbers = originalSSN.Substring(originalSSN.Length - 4);
        var leadingNumbers = originalSSN.Substring(0, originalSSN.Length - 4);
        var maskedLeadingNumbers = Regex.Replace(leadingNumbers, @"[0-9]", "X");
        return maskedLeadingNumbers + trailingNumbers;
    }
```

So "123-45-6789" becomes "XXX-XX-6789" 
and "12-1234567" becomes "XX-XXX4567".

Answer (score 0):

```
string originalSSN = Convert.ToString("123-456-789").PadLeft(9, '0');
int maskDigit = 6;
string maskSSN = originalSSN.Substring(originalSSN.Length - maskDigit, maskDigit);            
if (Regex.IsMatch(maskSSN, "(—)|(–)|(-)")) {
    int i = maskDigit;
    while (Regex.Replace(maskSSN, "(—)|(–)|(-)", "").Length < maskDigit) {
        i++;
        maskSSN = originalSSN.Substring(originalSSN.Length - i, i);
    }

    string[] ssnArray = Regex.Split(maskSSN, "(—)|(–)|(-)", RegexOptions.ExplicitCapture);
    if (ssnArray.Length > 1) {
        maskSSN = originalSSN.Substring(originalSSN.Length - maskDigit - (ssnArray.Length - 1), maskDigit + (ssnArray.Length - 1));
    }
}

maskSSN = maskSSN.PadLeft(9, '#');
```